# How to easily find why my application requires elevated permissions?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, elevated-privileges

As this is causing issues with dragdrop from non-elevated applications (Outlook), I would like to see if I can de-elevate my application. Not sure how to do that in an easy way.

The application is developed in VS2017

Comment: [This Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/573356/app-needs-elevated-privileges-to-run-why) suggests using SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Just run your app without elevation and see where it has problems because it tries to access protected resources. Sysinternals ProcMon might be of help here.

Comment: Visual Studio needs to be run as Administrator for a few purposes detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @MindSwipe he asked about his application, not about VS.

Comment: @KlausGütter well the title clearly asks about how to easily find why VS 2017 requires elevated permissions, which the I link I provided answers perfectly

Comment: @MindSwipe Indeed, this could be one interpretation of what they said. I read it as "my application that I compiled using VS2017".

Comment: @KlausGütter it's quite the confusing question, I interpreted it as asking why VS needs to be run as administrator because it's casing problems with other applications, namely Outlook

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I'll amend the title